# how to construct a unique pointer that points to a certain string

Tags: pointers, c++17, unique-ptr, stdstring

Given a string s e.g. `auto s = std::string("hello")`, how would you write code to make a unique pointer that points to a created copy of this string (not necessarily s) - I've tried many variations of `auto ptr = std::make_unique<std::string>(s)` but nothings seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
    std::string s = "ABCDE";
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<std::string>(s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
    s = "UVWXYZ";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

gives me output:

```
ABCDE
ABCDE
UVWXYZ
ABCDE
```

is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes exactly - my problem must lie elsewhere if your code is working.

Comment: I have the following two lines in my test file:
```
auto list = std::initializer_list<std::string>{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
  auto c = namespace::my_class<std::string, int>(list);
```
and in my_class, I have a constructor which goes:
```
  my_class(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
   for (auto element : list) {
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>(element);
    ptr_set_.insert(ptr);
   }
  }
```
Do you know if there's anything wrong with the above?

Comment: Your pointer will point at a copy of the string s, will it not?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work - I'll have to debug on my own. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr: Don't ever do that!

Why? Because an `std::string` *owns* the memory it uses as a buffer: The string frees this memory when it is destructed (if it's not inside the string object itself - small-string optimization); and it may reallocate it to reflect changes in the string's contents. But - a unique_ptr *also* owns the memory it points to, i.e. it also is responsible for freeing it when destructed.

So, if you create a unique pointer, pointing to a string's buffer, one of two things will probably happen:

1. You will try to access free'd memory
2. You will try to free the same stretch of memory twice

... so, really, just don't do that.

Comment: in my code I have a list of strings, and I need to construct a set of unique pointers such that these unique pointers will refer to the values of the aforementioned strings - would you know of any way to achieve this at all? (even if i have to somehow 'de-allocate' the former strings)

Comment: I tried std::move(s) and it seems to work - is there a more professional solution?

Comment: @user11508332: Why do you think you have to construct a set of unique pointers which "refer to the values of strings"? Also - perhaps you mean "unique pointers to strings"? Because that's at least not dangerous (albeit doesn't sound like a good idea).

Comment: When I dereference the unique pointers, I should get the strings from the original list - so I guess I mean "unique pointers to strings"